# Stop Kettle/Spoon from crashing with one line R script

Tags: r, statistics, pentaho, kettle, spoon

Let suppose there is a simple R script with only one statement:
q()

Using the R Script plugin in Pentaho Kettle/Spoon, executing the above R script causes Spoon/Kettle to crash.

How can we stop Kettle/Spoon from crashing abnormally with the above statement in our R script?

Kettle should instead stop executing the script and execution control should return to Kettle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a **return(value)** instead **q()** to expect kettle handle the value from R script and continue the common kettle row flow.

Comment: That's a possibility yes, but the quit is intentional to see if Kettle can still control the flow even if R plugin stops abnormally.